# group by value but only for continue value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

OK, the title is far from obvious, I could not explain it better.
Let's consider the table with columns (date, xvalue, some other columns), what I need is to group them by xvalue but only when they are not interrupted considering time (column date), so for example, for:

```
      Date |xvalue      |yvalue|
    1 Mar  |10          |1     |
    2 Mar  |10          |2     |
    3 Mar  |20          |6     |
    4 Mar  |20          |1     |
    5 Mar  |10          |4     |
    6 Mar  |10          |2     |
```

From the above data, I would like to get **three** rows, for the first xvalue==10, for xvalue==20 and again for xvalue==10 and for each group aggregate of the other values, for example for sum:

```
1 Mar, 10, 3
3 Mar, 20, 7
5 Mar, 10, 6
```

It's like query:

```
select min(date), xvalue, sum(yvalue) from t group by xvalue
```

Except above will merge 1,2,5 and 6th of March and I want them separately

Comment: so are you sure u wanna ignore March 2 and squash it to March 1?

Comment: SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  You need a column in the data that specifies the ordering for this question to make sense.

Comment: as @GordonLinoff mentioned, you should not find a solution for this problem in sql. However, you must find the appropriate design for the table.

Comment: I thought that order was obvious - it's a date. I will edit the question to clarify that

Comment: @ZbyszekSwirski . . . No, your rows do not obviously start with a date.  They would if you specified the date using a standard format, YYYY-MM-DD.  They would be more recognizable with a year, at least.

Answer (score 2):

This is an example of a gaps-and-islands problem.  But you need an ordering column.  With such a column, you can use the difference of row numbers:

```
select min(date), xvalue, sum(yvalue)
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by xvalue order by date) as seqnum_d,
             row_number() over (order by date) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by xvalue, (seqnum - seqnum_d)
order by min(date)
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=9fce313eefcbbcb0ba8c5e08b175bd58) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Sorry, but this does not work at all. I need to group by value, not by date.
Your query returns 6 rows not three (and no sum)

Comment: @ZbyszekSwirski . . . First, I think the code returned what you want.  Second, what you describe is just very small a tweak on the logic.

Comment: thanks, now it does! You have changed the group by. I should have spotted it. I will test it in a global problem. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Datas in a database are logically stored in mathematicl sets inside which there is absolutly no order and no way to have a default ordering. they are comparable to bags in which objects can move during their use.
So there is no solution to answer your query until you add a specific column to give the requested sort order that the user need to have...

Comment: A simple group by and sum will suffice.

Comment: @TanveerBadar - no, beause group by would group al 10s in the example and return two rows